# How to make an Email-Sending Program

Tags: c#, smtp

I have been trying for many days to create a program that can send emails . But all that I made used an SMTP Server. And unfortunately, it doesn't work on my computer. SO I desperately need an alternative. Could somebody tell me some other way to send emails ( without SMTP).

Thanks!

Comment: What went wrong with the SMTP approach?

Comment: Define "doesn't work."  SMTP is a pretty universal protocol for, you know, simple mail transfer.

Comment: @David, you forgot about MS Exchange, but I can understand why...

Comment: @Mike Pennington: I don't see what MS Exchange has to do with the question.  The OP is claiming that SMTP "doesn't work" (a term which he doesn't define or clarify) and I'm merely pointing out that SMTP is about as simple as email gets (hence the name).  He's probably better off fixing whatever's wrong with his setup than looking for a more complicated alternative, at least given the limited information presented in the question.

Comment: @David, it's not true to say SMTP is the *universal protocol*.  In fact, for transfer to recipients within corporate intranets, SMTP is in the minority due to the prevalence of junk from Redmond.  Honestly I meant it as humor, but I've never been very good at that ;-)

Answer (score 4):

[So You'd Like to Send Some Email](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html)...

Answer (score 0):

it really is not about ur computer? did u determine the SMTP server and host right? username and password? actually, everything is determined by ur SMTP server, unless ur sending it with ur own SMTP server and pop3 server via ur own server... for example, if ur sending it from a .asp page, or a .php page, if ur doymain gives u a free webmail then its easy to send an email, but if its a desktop application, u either need ur own webmail hosting account, or an SMTP server of google or yahoo...

its not whats wrong with the computer... check again...